# Do I need additional assumptions for this equality to hold?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, independence

Suppose I have three random variables $X_1,X_2, V$,  and I want the following condition to hold:

$E[X_1^2|X_2<V<X_1,X_1,X_2]=E[X_1^2|X_1]=h(X_1)$,

i.e., I want conditioning varibles $V$ and $X_2$ to drop from the conditioning set. I'm wondering whether this equality holds by construction without the need for adding any additional assumptions. This is because given the value of $X_1$ in the conditioning set, $E[X_1|X_2<V<X_1,X_1,X_2]=X_1^2$ . We don't need conditions such as $X_1,X_2, V$ being mutually independent to deliver this, right?

Comment: Yes, is is correct, for sure.

Comment: I don't know the solution, but I'd be cautious, since you're conditioning not only over a set of random variables, but also over an event. Imagine that $X_1 \sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$ and $X_2 \sim \text{Uniform}(10,11)$, then the event $X_2 < V < X_1$ has null probability and the expected value is undefined.